# Edit Object in Vector and return Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am new to programming. I am trying to make a Banking application, where a User enters their name and gets a Username set.
I am messing around with Classes for the first time.

1. I am trying to pass a std::vector to a function to add Data into it. Do I have to return the values that I want to set into the Vector? Or can I just edit the Vector in the subfunction, since a Vector is stored on the Heap?
2. How can I modify the Attributes of an Object in a Vector?

```
class Account {int something{}; };
Account Frank;
Frank.something =....
```

How can I do that in Vectors?

Comment: I dont have a person teaching me, I learn with books ;)

Comment: Questions 1 should answer itself if you learn about _references_ (there is probably a chapter about them in your textbook). The second question should be answered in a chapter about vectors or arrays. The notation is `vec[i].something = ...;` where `vec` is the vector object and `i` the index of the object you want to modify.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "return into the vector". If you're asking, whether it's necessary to create a new, modified vector and return that from the vector: no; there's the possibility of pass by reference. Whether the vector is allocated on the heap or stack makes no difference btw. Objects allocated on the heap or on the stack can both be passed by value or by reference.

Comment: return string; or whatever. If its on the Heap I only have to edit it once, since all Functions are messing with the same Vector. If I am passing it, then I would either have to pass a pointer or return it, which was my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a non-const reference of your vector to your function, e.g.

```
void add_value(std::vector<int>& values, int value) {
    values.push_back(value);
}

// later
std::vector<int> values;
add_value(values, 5);
// values now contains {5}
```

If you have a vector of objects you can first index one of them, then call a method or attribute

```
std::vector<Account> accounts;
// ... gets filled ...
accounts[i].do_something();  // call method
accounts[i].name;  // access public member
```